# Nav bar removed by angular router outlet

Tags: angular

I have a app in which I have a header and a sidebar. It looks like this:

```
<mat-drawer-container class="sidenav-container">

    <app-side-nav></app-side-nav>

  <mat-drawer-content>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Side nav contains 2 modules as clickable link (let say module1,module2). Module1 contains 3 components named `my identity,users and container.`[image]
Here is the container html:

```
   <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
      <a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['/identity/my-identity']">My 
     Identity</a>

      <a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['/identity/users']">Users</a>
    </<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
```

My plan was to navigate from container to identity or users. 
In the picture you can see the current page while I click on module1. But unfortunately, whenever I click on identity or user it loads the component properly but the nav menu disappears.

I want the following behavior: Clicking module1 should load `my identity` by default and I can navigate to users  without vanishing the nav menu. What correction should I do or how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have any demo url ?

Comment: not really  :( but nav menu disappear while i click .. i believe its happening because of router-outlink @NIVINCEN

Comment: Hopefully I think while clicking on Module1 you are loading container component.

Comment: Yes you are right..

Comment: can you please provide the route config?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your tabs `Identity` and `Users` are part of a single router outlet.

Try following this structure in your component containing them :

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>

</nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

use [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation) to implement it correctly.

You can then declare children to this route. This means that when done correctly, you will change the depth n°2 (the second `router-outlet`) only, instead of the first one.

But then again, consider providing a minimal & reproducible example of your issue if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: hi adding <router-outlet></router-outlet> do not solve the problem. I understand its happaning because of single routes. but do not know how i can solve this problem. any other solution that might help? @Maryannah

Comment: @Kazi because you're supposed to make the routes accordingly ... Again, provide a [mcve] if you want the code instead of just the principle.